# AngularJS dropdown choices issues

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a problem with the dropdown in an Angular.JS format.

I supposed to show the choices under the dropdown menu, which is the "Update" and "Delete". Unfortunately, it didn't show anything.

```
<ui-select ng-model="ctrl.OptionChoices" title="Update or Delete">

<ui-select-match placeholder="Choose the option for the item">{{select.option.name}}</ui-select-match>

<ui-select-choices repeat="existingUOMx.UnitOfMeasurementID as existingUOMx in ctrl.existingUOMsx | filter: $select.search">

<small ng-bind-html="existingUOMx.UnitOfMeasurementID | highlight: $select.search"> - </small>

<span ng-bind-html="existingUOMx.Description | highlight: $select.search"></span>

</ui-select-choices>

</ui-select>
```

Option-menu.js

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function $scope) {

var option = this;
$scope.optionChoice = 0; // choice int are 0
$scope.toggleOption = true;
$scope.option = [
    { name: "Update" },
    { name: "Delete" }, 

]
```

Thanks for the Help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use like this to bind dropdown value

```
<select>
<option>Choose the option for the item</option>
  <option ng-repeat="ItemsPerPageCount in option" value="{{ItemsPerPageCount.name}}" ng-bind="ItemsPerPageCount.name"></option>
</select>
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Yes it helped me and worked. Thanks!